# Web.config aruba ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection-string, aruba

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to connect my website to MySql on Aruba server.

I always get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I'm using this connection string now:

```
<add name="OfferteConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=example.org;User ID=xxxx;password=yyyy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<add name="OfferteConnectionString1" connectionString="Server=example.org;Database=Sql702732_1;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=yyyy;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Daniele, you should get the connection string in the control panel somewhere in the DB area/page. Just copy that one into your code and should work. Moreover, as the error says, is the DB configured to allow remote connections? Normally this is done when you create the DB. Last but not less important, if you have attempted several times to access the db unsuccessfully, they may have banned your ip address.Make the above checks and try again.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find this section in mysql control panel. I'm becoming crazy, I can't understand >_>

Comment: But, are you trying to connect from a website hosted on their server or from a desktop application?

Comment: From a website hosted on their server!

Comment: <add name="objConn" connectionString="Data Source=XX.XX.XX.XX;User ID=MSSqlXXXX;password=YYYYYY" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> This is what they say. but you need the server name/ip. Open a ticked otherwise you will never get the right one. Buona fortuna.

Comment: I was thinking... I use "SqlConnection" in CodeBehind... can is it a problem if I don't use MySqlConnection?

Comment: What? The connection string shall be in the web.config file.

Comment: @DanieleNekoLuciani what is this `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>` ? What are you using `SQLServer` or `MySQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection string and get it straight which DBMS you are using .

Connection string `SQL Server`

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Connection string `MySQL`

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

You have declared you are using MySQL however your connection string defines

```
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient
```

If everything is correct then i will suggest you to check some settings as suggested in this [Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I have attached an image to see where you can find the connection string (Aruba Service)

[image: https://mssql.aruba.it/mylittleadmin.aspx]